# Laravel Eloquent Query -> Undefined Variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Attached is a screenshot of the error I am facing. I have the log show the value of the $team variable. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Show your code??

Comment: It should be `function($query) use ($team)` (string: 18) to import this variable into closure from parent scope

Comment: Thanks Dan. You were the first to answer, but since it is a comment, I cant upvote you.

Comment: You might also find using a good IDE like PhpStorm help debug before you test. If you use PhpStorm for example you'd have seen this mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have access to parents variables from a closure, you need to explicitly send variables to the closure with **use** keyword

```
function($query) use ($team)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use forget to use $team variable inside your closure. It must be `function($query) use ($team)`

```
$data = User::whereHas('roles' => function($query) use ($team) {
    $query->where('role_code', '=', $team)
})->get();
```